# Trying to break down this promise example

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I've been learning a bit about promises and I came across this example but can't quite understand how it's working. Would someone be able to help break this down into steps so I can understand please, I'm mostly thrown by the cancel parameter and how it's being used. I've tried running the code in console too but I'm still confused. Thanks.

```
    const wait = (
  time,
  cancel = Promise.reject()
) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const timer = setTimeout(resolve, time);
  const noop = () => {};

  cancel.then(() => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    reject(new Error('Cancelled'));
  }, noop);
});

const shouldCancel = Promise.resolve(); // Yes, cancel
// const shouldCancel = Promise.reject(); // No cancel

wait(2000, shouldCancel).then(
  () => console.log('Hello!'),
  (e) => console.log(e) // [Error: Cancelled]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, `Promise.resolve()` returns a Promise object that is resolved. Similarly, `Promise.reject()` returns a rejected Promise object.

The `cancel` variable holds a rejected or resolved Promise object (a rejected Promise by default).

In case the Promise object within `cancel` is resolved, it will immediately clear out the timer set in the `timer` variable and reject it's parent Promise. You can see this in the comment on this line:

```
const shouldCancel = Promise.resolve(); // Yes, cancel
```

In case the Promise object within `cancel` is rejected, it will not clear out the timer, since it won't get to run the lines of code where the timer is cleared out and will instead run the `noop` function which is an empty no operations funciton. Thus it will let the timer follow it's course and finally resolve it's parent Promise. You can see this in the comment on this line:

```
// const shouldCancel = Promise.reject(); // No cancel
```

So the timer will follow it's natural course if `shouldCancel = Promise.reject()` and return a resolved Promise. If `shouldCancel = Promise.resolve()`, the timer will get cancelled, and the Promise will be rejected.

Comment: thanks, I think I follow a bit more now, but why in the case where the cancel promise is rejected and the noop function runs does it wait for the parent promise to resolve rather than returning undefined back into the outside "then" function, similar to when the cancel promise is resolved and the timer is cleared and the reject function is called? In this case it doesn't wait for the parent Promise to reject does it?

Comment: Also interestingly the string 'cancelled' isn't logged in the outside then onReject function, I can't see why that is.

Comment: A promise only returns once it is resolved or rejected. Since the `noop` function does neither, the promise waits for the timer to end before it is finally resolved

Comment: The later part where it says `console.log(e)` is only meant to run when the promise is rejected. This `.then()` syntax accepts two callback functions, the first one is called only if the Promise is resolved. The second one is called only if the Promise is rejected